# How to find optimum number of cpu cores for a workload

Tags: cpu, threads

Following bar graph shows maximum percentage cpu utilization of F16sv2 (16vcpu &32GB) azure virtual machine in last 30 days. Only sometimes CPU usage goes more than 60 percentage.

1. How to find the right number of CPU cores for the workload so cpu never goes under utilized?
2. What factors should we consider while doing scale up/down on of VM from historical data?
3. Do I get almost full cpu utilization if I scale down the vm to F8sv2 (8vcpu & 16GB). 16GB ram is okay for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a supervisor that allocates CPUs exclusively to one VM then you should use a different supervisor.

You have n real CPUs. The can do n times x amounts of work per second. Whether your VM has 2 CPUs at 100% or 4 CPUs at 50% makes very little difference. Unless you pay per CPU